# Program with synchronized and non-sycnhronized blocks execution

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have two methods Synchronized and non-synchronized. Two threads t1 accessing Synchronized method and t2 with non-synchronized method. Will T2 wait till T1 finishes and exits synchronized block? How is this done?

Answer (score 1):

All synchronized blocks synchronized on the same object can only have one thread executing inside them at a time. All other threads attempting to enter the synchronized block are blocked until the thread inside the synchronized block exits the block. 
Only if t1 and t2 are trying to access same synchronized method of same object, then other have to wait until first one finishes it's job. However, this is not case as per your question. See here http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/synchronized-in-java/

Comment: Thank you Prashanth for your clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Synchronized method will effect only threads using this method, therefore in your case T2 isn't using the method and won't wait for T1

Read more about [Synchronized Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html)

> When one thread is executing a synchronized method for an object, all other threads that invoke synchronized methods for the same object block